# jQuery UI Tabs: Disable "First Tab"

Tags: jquery-ui, tabs

I'm looking to load jQuery UI Tabs widget without the "First Tab" being loaded by default.

I tried the following, but the first tab is still being shown:

```
 $('#tabs').tabs({
      selected: -1
 });
```

Comment: By the way `A negative value selects panels going backward from the last panel.` [active](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the [collapsible](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-collapsible) option to `true` and the [active](http://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#option-active) option to `false`:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({
    collapsible: true,
    active: false
});
```